# How to configure chef to re-bootstrap on instance termination?

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra

I can't seem to find any documentation anywhere on how this is possible.

If I knife bootstrap a new AWS instance, and then a few weeks later that machine goes offline, I would like my Chef server to detect this, and bootstrap a new machine.

I understand how to make chef create a new AWS instance, and bootstrap the instance.

I do not know how to make chef detect that a previously deployed box is no longer available.

I can use the chef API to search for existing nodes.  But I do not know how to check that those nodes are still accessible over network, or how to run this check regularly.

I believe I am missing something simple?  Most resources I have found on this issue assume that this doesn't need to be discussed, as it is self-evident?

Comment: Do you mean you are using chef-provisioning? Because overall this is not something Chef does at all.

Comment: If you run chef in regular intervals, you can parse `knife status` output (you will get data when node converged last time) or you can query chef server directly. You would have to combine this with some kind of script.